# isExternalStorageRemovable throws Illegal exception even if SD card is attached with device

Tags: android, android-file, android-developer-api

I got paths for my application using `getExternalFilesDirs` api. After that for each file I am calling `isExternalStorageRemovable`(file_name) to check whether storage is removable or not.
But it throws exception:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find storage device at *_given_path_*

What could be the possible reason for this. SD card is still inserted in device only.

Comment: What path are you using?  Are you sure its correct?  Post your code and the full stack trace.

Comment: You better show your code than talking about it.